# How to implement dark/light mode in vue3?

Tags: css, vuejs3, darkmode, vueuse

I'm wondering how to add dark/light mode to my Vue 3 project. I'm aware of **`useDark`** and **`useToggle`** from '@vueuse/core', but I'm unsure how to implement them in every component of my application.

```
const isDark = useDark({
  selector: 'body',
  attribute: 'color-scheme',
  valueDark: 'dark',
  valueLight: 'light',
})
```

Should I create multiple objects for every HTML element on my page? It seems even more time-consuming than the previous option. And how can I use **`isDark`** in my child components?

Currently, I'm using a Pinia store to store information about whether the mode is set to dark or light. I then use this value in every HTML element of every component to apply the 'dark' or 'light' class. However, this approach is time-consuming, and I believe there must be a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement dark/light mode in every child component. Instead you just need to add it to the app/root component. Something like

```
<template>
  <div :class="{ dark: isDark }">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
...
<script setup>
const darkModeStore = useDarkModeStore();
const isDark = computed(() => darkModeStore.mode === 'dark');
</script>
```

And in your style general

```
<style>
/* Styles for dark mode */
.dark h1 {
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Or in child specific

```
<style scoped>
.dark .child-component h1 {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Oh, thats how it works. Thank you very much.